# Sorting a table by date in Excel, rows with the same date are not reversed as I expected?

Tags: excel

When sorting by the date I was surprised excel does not reverse the rows of data within the same dates.

I have the following table of data:

```
Date          Narrative                                    Debit
07 12 2020    LIBERTY RICHMOND AUS                         48.75
07 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   5.5
07 12 2020    Hungry Jacks Fulham AUS                      7.7
07 12 2020    TICKETS-INSTRUMENTALVO BELROSE AUS           154.25
07 12 2020    House & Garden Richmond AUS                  46.9
07 12 2020    BIG W           0563 HALLETT COV AUS         40
07 12 2020    BIG W           0563 HALLETT COV AUS         49
07 12 2020    ALDI STORES - PLYMPTON PLYMPTON AUS          192.22
07 12 2020    PAYPAL *EBAY AU 33333333333AUS               5.75
07 12 2020    CRED VOUCHER PP*7301CODE 44444444444AUS      -2
07 12 2020    PP*7301CODE 4029357733 AUS                   2
07 12 2020    ZipPay P114300123 Sydney AUS                 120
07 12 2020    JJ`S FONE CASES HALLETT COV AUS              33
07 12 2020    LOCKLEYS OPERATIONS FULHAM AUS               32
07 12 2020    LOCKLEYS OPERATIONS FULHAM AUS               12
07 12 2020    ADIDAS AUSTRALIA MULGRAVE                    109.2
08 12 2020    CRED VOUCHER BUNNINGS 356000 MILE END AUS    -5.25
08 12 2020    EST OVEST - OSTERIA CA ADELAIDE AUS          4.9
08 12 2020    ADELAIDE METRO ADELAIDE AUS                  15
08 12 2020    DIT - EZYREG ADELAIDE AUS                    56.09
08 12 2020    MCDONALDS DT 1727 WEST RICHMO AUS            29.3
08 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   23
08 12 2020    PAYPAL *BUNNINGSGRO 9999999999 AUS           3.46
09 12 2020    WOOLWORTHS      5626 HILTON AUS              48.3
09 12 2020    PAYPAL *BUNNINGSGRO 55555555555AUS           14.18
10 12 2020    KMART 1005 KURRALTA PA AUS                   15
11 12 2020    MYER  ADELAIDE CITY ADELAIDE AUS             159.9
11 12 2020    Golden Boy Adelaide AUS                      167.83
11 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   5.5
11 12 2020    SUSHI HUB RUNDLE MAL ADELAIDE AUS            6.7
11 12 2020    COLES 0406 KURRALTA PA AUS                   54.38
```

When sorting by 'Date', either A-Z or Z-A the dates sort in the correct order but the rows within the groups of 'same dates' do not reverse. For example, the above table is now sorted (by Date) Z-A:

```
Date          Narrative                                    Debit
11 12 2020    MYER  ADELAIDE CITY ADELAIDE AUS             159.9
11 12 2020    Golden Boy Adelaide AUS                      167.83
11 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   5.5
11 12 2020    SUSHI HUB RUNDLE MAL ADELAIDE AUS            6.7
11 12 2020    COLES 0406 KURRALTA PA AUS                   54.38
10 12 2020    KMART 1005 KURRALTA PA AUS                   15
09 12 2020    WOOLWORTHS      5626 HILTON AUS              48.3
09 12 2020    PAYPAL *BUNNINGSGRO 5555555555 AUS           14.18
08 12 2020    CRED VOUCHER BUNNINGS 356000 MILE END AUS    -5.25
08 12 2020    EST OVEST - OSTERIA CA ADELAIDE AUS          4.9
08 12 2020    ADELAIDE METRO ADELAIDE AUS                  15
08 12 2020    DIT - EZYREG ADELAIDE AUS                    56.09
08 12 2020    MCDONALDS DT 1727 WEST RICHMO AUS            29.3
08 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   23
08 12 2020    PAYPAL *BUNNINGSGRO 5555555555 AUS           3.46
07 12 2020    LIBERTY RICHMOND AUS                         48.75
07 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   5.5
07 12 2020    Hungry Jacks Fulham AUS                      7.7
07 12 2020    TICKETS-INSTRUMENTALVO BELROSE AUS           154.25
07 12 2020    House & Garden Richmond AUS                  46.9
07 12 2020    BIG W           0563 HALLETT COV AUS         40
07 12 2020    BIG W           0563 HALLETT COV AUS         49
07 12 2020    ALDI STORES - PLYMPTON PLYMPTON AUS          192.22
07 12 2020    PAYPAL *EBAY AU 44444444444AUS               5.75
07 12 2020    CRED VOUCHER PP*7301CODE 33333333333AUS      -2
07 12 2020    PP*7301CODE 4029357733 AUS                   2
07 12 2020    ZipPay P114300123 Sydney AUS                 120
07 12 2020    JJ`S FONE CASES HALLETT COV AUS              33
07 12 2020    LOCKLEYS OPERATIONS FULHAM AUS               32
07 12 2020    LOCKLEYS OPERATIONS FULHAM AUS               12
07 12 2020    ADIDAS AUSTRALIA MULGRAVE                    109.2
```

As you can see the dates have reversed but the rows with the same dates have not. What I want (perhaps expected?) is for the result to be the following:

```
Date          Narrative                                    Debit
11 12 2020    COLES 0406 KURRALTA PA AUS                   54.38
11 12 2020    SUSHI HUB RUNDLE MAL ADELAIDE AUS            6.7
11 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   5.5
11 12 2020    Golden Boy Adelaide AUS                      167.83
11 12 2020    MYER  ADELAIDE CITY ADELAIDE AUS             159.9
10 12 2020    KMART 1005 KURRALTA PA AUS                   15
09 12 2020    PAYPAL *BUNNINGSGRO 22222222222AUS           14.18
09 12 2020    WOOLWORTHS      5626 HILTON AUS              48.3
08 12 2020    PAYPAL *BUNNINGSGRO 33333333333AUS           3.46
08 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   23
08 12 2020    MCDONALDS DT 1727 WEST RICHMO AUS            29.3
08 12 2020    DIT - EZYREG ADELAIDE AUS                    56.09
08 12 2020    ADELAIDE METRO ADELAIDE AUS                  15
08 12 2020    EST OVEST - OSTERIA CA ADELAIDE AUS          4.9
08 12 2020    CRED VOUCHER BUNNINGS 356000 MILE END AUS    -5.25
07 12 2020    ADIDAS AUSTRALIA MULGRAVE                    109.2
07 12 2020    LOCKLEYS OPERATIONS FULHAM AUS               12
07 12 2020    LOCKLEYS OPERATIONS FULHAM AUS               32
07 12 2020    JJ`S FONE CASES HALLETT COV AUS              33
07 12 2020    ZipPay P114300123 Sydney AUS                 120
07 12 2020    PP*7301CODE 4029357733 AUS                   2
07 12 2020    CRED VOUCHER PP*7301CODE 11111111111AUS      -2
07 12 2020    PAYPAL *EBAY AU 4029357733 AUS               5.75
07 12 2020    ALDI STORES - PLYMPTON PLYMPTON AUS          192.22
07 12 2020    BIG W           0563 HALLETT COV AUS         49
07 12 2020    BIG W           0563 HALLETT COV AUS         40
07 12 2020    House & Garden Richmond AUS                  46.9
07 12 2020    TICKETS-INSTRUMENTALVO BELROSE AUS           154.25
07 12 2020    Hungry Jacks Fulham AUS                      7.7
07 12 2020    E10 ESPRESSO MARLESTON AUS                   5.5
07 12 2020    LIBERTY RICHMOND AUS                         48.75
```

The above snippet is part of a much larger table of data. I have found and used a 'ReverseRange' macro which works how I want but when I clear the table filters to reveal the full data set the reversed data above stays reversed unless I reverse it back again before clearing the table filters.

Another option I thought about was using a helper column with an incrementing count and using this as a secondary sort.

Am I missing something with how excel sorts 'by date'?

Comment: The ordered dates are just that. There is no reason for excel to move them when they are already in order even though you are changing where the other groups go. Now if the time was stored with the dates you would get a different order.

Comment: Fair enough. Your right about the time, but that information is not available. I think in the end I'll use a separate helper column with an incrementing counter. The reason for this is that I want them in the same order as they appear on my credit card statement (which is the same order as I add them).

Comment: Thanks to RetiredGeek for the idea to store a time with my dates, which I never thought about doing, this solved my problem. I now use the windows function 'GetSystemTime' to extract 'wMilliseconds' from the SYSTEMTIME struct. I needed this granularity as adding rows to my table takes under 1 second per row of data. I then use `Format(c(1) & " " & Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss") & "." & t.wMilliseconds, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000")` (where c(1) is the date portion) to construct the formatted Date/Time. I then format the table cell with `dd mm yyyy` so only the date is displayed in the cell.